# Troubleshooting occasional timeout of select() in windows

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm having an occasional problem with select() timing out on me.  I have it set for twenty seconds.  The system will handle 100's of transactions correctly, but occasionally one fails with the selet timing out.  It does about 1 transaction every few seconds, opening and closing the tcp conncetion with each transaction.  I thought the server my app was connecting to might have to many connection attempts pending, but no 4226 events are showing up in the logs

One more point thing I noticed when using wireshark that I'm getting a SYN,RST in response to the SYN I am appearently sending.  This only happens a few times over the first second or two, then I don't see any more activity in Wireshark

Comment: Please post the code you are using.  Then we can analyze it and make some suggestions.  It sounds to me like you are attempting to make a connection but not checking it for success then blocking on select for a response.  But it's impossible to tell without the code...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rebuild your timeout value each time you go into select. select apparently can modify this value:

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

```
 select() may update the timeout argument to indicate how much time was left.
```

If it modifies it, and you reuse it for input back into select, you may not be getting the timeout you expect. This is a linux man page though, your mileage may very with Windows, especially as the man page states:

> the glibc pselect() function does not
>   modify its timeout argument; this is
>   the behaviour required by POSIX.1-2001

Somewhat of a speculative answer, hopefully it's helpful. Maybe if you post some code we can confirm/deny this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are missing errors on asynchronous connect. Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574533/).